# C++ - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This code causes a segmentation fault, but I don't know why. It must be in the first while loop in the main function. Could someone tell me, what's causing the segmentation fault or where the mistake is?
The input file is:

 1 2 

 2 3

 3 4 

 4 5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

const int maxRec = 4;
int area;

struct Rectangle {
  int h, w, area;
  Rectangle(int i = 0, int j = 0) {
    h = j;
    w = i;
    area = h*w;
  }

  void swap() {
    h ^= w ^= h ^= w;
  }

  void wh() {
    if(h < w) return;
    swap();
  }

  friend bool operator < (const Rectangle a, const Rectangle b) {
    return (a.w < b.w);
  }

  friend bool operator == (const Rectangle a, const Rectangle b) {
    return (a.h == b.h) && (a.w == b.w);
  }
};

list<Rectangle> square;

Rectangle first(const Rectangle rect[maxRec]) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  for(int a = 0; a < maxRec; a++) {
    i += rect[i].w;
    j = max(j, rect[a].h);
  }
  return Rectangle(i,j);
}

Rectangle second(const Rectangle rect[maxRec]) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  for(int a = 1; a < maxRec; a++) {
    i += rect[a].w;
    j = max(j, rect[i].h);
  }
  return Rectangle(max(i, rect[0].w),j+rect[0].h);
}

Rectangle third(const Rectangle rect[maxRec]) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  for(int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    i += rect[a].w;
    j += rect[a].h;
  }
  return Rectangle(rect[3].w + max(i,rect[2].w), max(j+rect[2].h,rect[3].h));
}

Rectangle fourth(const Rectangle rect[maxRec]) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  for(int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    i = max(rect[a].w, i);
    j += rect[a].h;
  }
  return Rectangle(rect[2].w+rect[3].w+i, max(rect[3].h,max(rect[2].h,j)));
}

Rectangle fifth(const Rectangle rect[maxRec]) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  i = max(rect[0].h+rect[2].h, rect[1].h+rect[3].h);

  if (rect[1].h >= rect[2].h + rect[3].h) {
    j = max(rect[2].w, rect[3].w) + rect[1].w;
    return Rectangle(i, max(j, rect[0].w));
  }
  if (rect[1].h > rect[2].h) {
    j = max(rect[2].w, rect[3].w);
    return Rectangle(i, max(j + rect[1].w, rect[0].w + rect[3].w));
  }
  if (rect[2].h >= rect[0].h + rect[1].h) {
    j = max(rect[0].w, rect[1].w) + rect[2].w;
    return Rectangle(i, max(j, rect[3].w));
  }
  if (rect[2].h > rect[1].h) {
    j = max(rect[1].w, rect[0].w);
    return Rectangle(i, max(j + rect[2].w, rect[0].w + rect[3].w));
  }
  j = max(rect[0].w + rect[3].w, rect[1].w + rect[2].w);
  return Rectangle(i, j);
}

void minArea(const Rectangle sq) {
  if(sq.area > area) return;

  Rectangle tempRect = sq;
  tempRect.wh();
  if(tempRect.area < area) {
    area = tempRect.area;
    square.clear();
  }
  square.push_back(tempRect);
}

void pack(const Rectangle rect[maxRec]) {
  minArea(first(rect));
  minArea(second(rect));
  minArea(third(rect));
  minArea(fourth(rect));
  minArea(fifth(rect));
}

int main() {
  ofstream fout ("packrec.out");
  ifstream fin ("packrec.in");

  Rectangle rect[maxRec];
  Rectangle rectTemp[maxRec];

  int a, b;
  int permutation[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
  while(fin >> a >> b) {
    square.clear();
    area = 1000000;
    rect[permutation[0]] = Rectangle(a,b);

    for(int i = 1; i < maxRec; i++) {
       fin >> a >> b;
       rect[i] = Rectangle(a,b);
    }

    do {
      for(int c = 0; c < 16; c++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < maxRec; j++) {
           rectTemp[j] = rect[permutation[j]];
            if(c & (1<<j)) {
               rectTemp[j].swap();
             }
         }
         pack(rectTemp);
      }
    } while(next_permutation(permutation, permutation+4));
    square.sort();
    square.unique();
    cout << area << endl;

    while(!square.empty()) {
      int i = square.front().h;
      int j = square.front().w;
      cout << i << " " << j << endl;
      square.pop_front();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this on your own? Do you know in what line the segfault occurs? If you don't yet know how to use a debugger, this would be a great time to start... Since you don't show what is in your input file it is difficult for anyone else to debug this for you...

Comment: You could start the debugging process by adding some console output or if your using an IDE that sports this, since break points to isolate the location of the fault

Comment: Why on Earth are you writing code that is difficult to read' i.e. `h ^= w ^= h ^= w;`. Worried about the job?

Comment: It compiles and runs for me.  It doesn't produce any output because I guess it can't find the input file.  Apparently it only dies when there is an input file.  What does the input file look like?

Comment: @EdHeal It's the most descriptive function name in the entire code sample.

Comment: @remyabel - Glad he does not work for use unless (s)he is good at making tea

Comment: When I hear `swap` I usually think 'swapping' one rectangle with another -- not swapping the width of a rectangle with its height.

Comment: @greatwolf Good point - transpose() would be a better name for it.

Comment: My rate for debugging crappy code is 100 USD/h, I'll be happy to join you!

Comment: You have a bug in first(), (gdb) bt
#0  0x08048c50 in first(Rectangle const*) ()
#1  0x08049242 in pack(Rectangle const*) ()
#2  0x08049610 in main ()

Comment: the input file is:

1 2\n
2 3\n
3 4\n
4 5\n

Answer (score 4):

```
Rectangle first(const Rectangle rect[maxRec]) {
 int i = 0, j = 0;
 for(int a = 0; a < maxRec; a++) {
     i += rect[i].w;
 //            ^------- You're adding a rectangle width to a list index
    j = max(j, rect[a].h);
 }
 return Rectangle(i,j);
}
```

This error is made in at least one other place in your code. This easily happens with you use variable names (e.g. `i`, `j`) as list indices in some parts of the code, and rectangle dimensions in another. Choosing a consistent convention will help to prevent these kinds of mistakes. A common convention is to use `i`, `j` as index variables. Use `w`, `h` for width, height, etc.

Comment: Better still, use `width`, `height` for width, height, etc!

Comment: @Matt: Thank you. I probably would not have seen that. :)